# IOS, ARC, Property: (readwrite, nonatomic) vs (radwrite, retain, nonatomic)

Tags: ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am have read up some tutorials on ARC and am still left a bit confused on properties declarations. I wrote most most my code using the following pattern:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) PlayerData* playerData;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) MusicLayer* musicLayer;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) bool isPowerUpAvailable;
```

Now that I finally started to deal with memory leaks XCode suggested me that in some bits of code I should have added the "retain" keyword in the property declaration.

Using ARC I thought I shouldn't "Bother" about retain counts anymore. Is there some concept I am not getting or missing?  Any tutorial references or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC is will retain object based on the property declaration, you should use `strong` for properties that need to be retained and `weak` for properties that do not need to be retained.

`weak` properties are also nilled when the object is deallocated.

The compiler will always assume that properties are `readwrite` so there is no need to declare then this way.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) PlayerData* playerData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MusicLayer* musicLayer;
// Need use assign since strong is for objects only.
@property (assign, nonatomic) bool isPowerUpAvailable;
```

Comment: Thanks, can accept the answer only in 5 minutes due to SO. Was wondering.. what are the cases in which I would want a weak reference? Am I right in saying that for "most" of the cases a strong reference is preferred?

Comment: Yes in most cases `strong` will do, but like for a `delegate` property  `weak` will be better, since the delegate could also be retaining the object for which it is the delegate.

Comment: So for instance, if I create an object (say A) in a class and then pass this object in the constructor of B, then I should declare the "receiving" pointer in B as delagate property?

Comment: No that is just a normal property, a delegate is when an object call methods on an other class, like `UITableView` does when a user selects a row. Since mostly these calles delegate and owner are the some `weak` is used.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of got it. In my case I got a main scene class that handles the "logic" of the game. Then I got some "child" class that is added to the main scene class where I load the level specific data (sprites). From the logic class init I schedule a call to an "update" method and at each update I call the "move" method in the "child" class. The sprites are added to the main class but in the child class I keep an array with references to the sprites in order to allow the "move" method to actually move them. Does this sound dangerous :)?

Comment: In other words, shoudl I rethink everything or given it doesn't seem to leak that bit of code keep it and "save" development time?

Comment: If you are not leaking (use the profiler and analyzer) you should be fine.

Comment: Don't forget `copy` for objects of class clusters with mutable immutable pairs most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer continue to use your code, you can exclude ARC only on the specific file `.m` you want:

Go to **Targets > Build Phases > Compile Sources** and select your `.m` file double click on right column of the selection and add `-fno-objc-arc` so you are exclude `ARC` only a selected file.

Or if you want to convert all application to new code with ARC, after make a Backup of you project, go to:

**Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC** and after this do the same but click on **Convert to modern Objective-C Sintax**

here the screen:

[image]
**Pay attention not always working before to try duplicate your project!**

Hope this help you